# How do I split a string with several delimiters, but only once on each delimiter? Python

Tags: python, split, csv

I am trying to split a string such as the one below, with all of the delimiters below, but only once.

`string = 'it; seems; like\ta good\tday to watch\va\vmovie.'`

`delimiters = '\t \v ;'`

The output, in this case, would be:

`['it', ' seems; like', 'a good\tday to watch', 'a\vmovie.']`

Obviously the example above is a nonsense example, but I am trying to learn whether or not this is possible. Would a fairly involved regex be in order?

Apologies if this question had been asked before. I did a fair bit of searching and could not find something quite like my example. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple algorithm would do,

```
test_string = r'it; seems; like\ta good\tday to watch\va\vmovie.'

delimiters = [r'\t', r'\v', ';']

# find the index of each first occurence and sort it
delimiters = sorted(delimiters, key=lambda delimiter: test_string.find(delimiter))

splitted_string = [test_string]

# perform split with option maxsplit
for index, delimiter in enumerate(delimiters):
    if delimiter in splitted_string[-1]:
        splitted_string += splitted_string[-1].split(delimiter, maxsplit=1)
        splitted_string.pop(index)

print(splitted_string)
# ['it', ' seems; like', 'a good\\tday to watch', 'a\\vmovie.']
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
import re

def split_once_by(s, delims):
    delims = set(delims)
    parts = []
    while delims:
        delim_re = '({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(d) for d in delims))
        result = re.split(delim_re, s, maxsplit=1)
        if len(result) == 3:
            first, delim, s = result
            parts.append(first)
            delims.remove(delim)
        else:
            break
    
    parts.append(s)
    return parts
```

Example:

```
>>> split_once_by('it; seems; like\ta good\tday to watch\va\vmovie.', '\t\v;')
['it', ' seems; like', 'a good\tday to watch', 'a\x0bmovie.']
```

---

Burning Alcohol's answer inspired me to write this (IMO) better function:

```
def split_once_by(s, delims):
    split_points = sorted((s.find(d), -len(d), d) for d in delims)
    start = 0
    for stop, _longest_first, d in split_points:
        if stop < start: continue
        yield s[start:stop]
        start = stop + len(d)
    yield s[start:]
```

with usage:

```
>>> list(split_once_by('it; seems; like\ta good\tday to watch\va\vmovie.', '\t\v;'))
['it', ' seems; like', 'a good\tday to watch', 'a\x0bmovie.']
```

Comment: Thank you; this was helpful, and I appreciate you going through the process again to come up with another answer as well.

Comment: Upvoted this answer for it is using less memory, but the logic of the @orlp's and mine should be the same. Glad my answer can inspire a discussion!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a list of patterns and apply them once:

```
string = 'it; seems; like\ta good\tday to watch\va\vmovie.'
patterns = ['\t', '\v', ';']

for pattern in patterns:
    string = '*****'.join(string.split(pattern, maxsplit=1)) 

print(string.split('*****'))
```

Output:

```
['it', ' seems; like', 'a good\tday to watch', 'a\x0bmovie.']
```

So, what is `"*****"` ??

On each iteration, when you apply the `split` method you get a list. So, in the next iteration, You can't apply the `.split ()` method (because you have a list), so you have to join each value of that list with some weird character like `"****"` or `"@@@"` or `"^^^^^^^"` or whatever you want, in order to re-apply the split () in the next iteration.
Finally, for each `"*****"` on your string, you will have one pattern of the list, so you can use this to make a final split.

Comment: What if the input contains `*****`?

Comment: in each iteration, when you apply split you get a list. So, in the next iteration I cant apply .split() (because I have a list), so I join that list with some weird character like "****", in order to re-apply the split() method

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What if the input string contains `****` or whatever you choose as 'something weird'?

Comment: I put an example to clarify my answer.

Comment: I understand your answer, my question is a pedagogical one to try and make you realize the issue with your answer.

Comment: Is just a way to keep the split of the last iteration on my loop. If your string contains "******" you can use another character, like a Russian character or something like that

Comment: Thank you for your answer; this was helpful!